# Is there a better split function for terminal?

Tags: terminal, split

I'm trying to split a very big CSV file into smaller more manageable ones. I've tried `split` but it seems that it tops out at [676 files](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/split.htm).

The CSV file I have is in excess of 80mb and I'd like to split it into 50 line files.

**Note** by *better* I mean one that uses a numbering structure instead of `split`'s a-z sequencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` is the right tool, the problem is that the suffix is only 2 long `26^2 = 676`, if you make it longer you should be fine:

```
split -a LEN file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'cat' to number each line and pipe the output to 'grep' with params to only print n lines